# Simulating network hops on a single Linux box

Tags: linux, networking, routes, iptables

I'm trying to simulate many network hops, similar to [Star Wars Traceroute](http://beaglenetworks.net/post/42707829171/star-wars-traceroute). The author provided a script [here](http://beaglenetworks.net/post/42707829171/star-wars-traceroute), however it's designed for Cisco routers by using `vrf`, rather than Linux.

Here is my current attempt;

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

ifconfig br0 172.16.100.1 netmask 255.255.255.0
ifconfig br0:1 172.16.101.1 netmask 255.255.255.0
ifconfig br0:2 172.16.102.1 netmask 255.255.255.0
ifconfig br0:2 172.16.103.1 netmask 255.255.255.0

ip rule add iif br0 table 100
ip rule add iif br0:1 table 101
ip rule add iif br0:2 table 102

ip route add default table 100 dev 172.16.101.1
ip route add default table 101 dev 172.16.102.1
ip route add default table 102 dev 172.16.103.1

ping -I br0 172.16.103.2
```

I've tried to accomplish the same thing using [Source Based Routing](https://superuser.com/questions/376667/how-to-route-only-specific-subnet-source-ip-to-a-particular-interface), which apparently reproduces the effects of `vrf`, see [here](https://renard.chezwam.org/blog/2014/09/vrf-on-linux/index.html), but attaching `tcpdump -i br0` shows no traffic at all, and the packets are instead being picked up on `lo0`.

Alternative solutions seem to include mangling source IPs and other trickery using `iptables` which feels quite dirty, so I'm not sure where to focus my efforts.

Any tips/pointers would be appreciated

Comment: I've actually managed to reproduce this myself using `netns`, I'll share the final solution in the morning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made this idea into a script for those still finding this question trying to make their own Star Wars Traceroute using Linux.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# traceroute fun with linux namespaces
#  each namespace is basically a router we connect
#  to each other using fancy /32 networking
#
# scott nicholas <scott@nicholas.one> 2018-10-27
#

# how many levels deep are we going?
depth=16
prefix=192.168.99.

# can change function easily or just pre-populate ip array
calcip() { printf '%s%d' "$prefix" $((63 + i)); }

# instead of special casing things, if we bind init's netns into a name
# all of the code can use "-n ns"
touch /var/run/netns/default
mount --bind /proc/1/ns/net /var/run/netns/default

ns[0]=default if[0]=root ip[0]=${prefix}1

for ((i = 1; i <= depth; i++)); do
  ns[i]=hop$i if[i]=hop$i ip[i]=$(calcip $i)

  ip netns add "${ns[i]}"
  # interfaces are named by whom is on the other side
  # so it's kinda flip-flopped looking.
  ip -n "${ns[i-1]}" link add "${if[i]}" type veth peer name "${if[i-1]}" \
    netns "${ns[i]}"

  ip -n "${ns[i]}" a a "${ip[i]}"/32 dev "${if[i-1]}"

  # interfaces must be up before adding routes
  ip -n "${ns[i-1]}" link set "${if[i]}"   up
  ip -n "${ns[i  ]}" link set lo           up
  ip -n "${ns[i  ]}" link set "${if[i-1]}" up

  ip -n "${ns[i-1]}" route add "${ip[i  ]}" dev "${if[i]}"
  ip -n "${ns[i  ]}" route add "${ip[i-1]}" dev "${if[i-1]}"
  ip -n "${ns[i  ]}" route add default      via "${ip[i-1]}"

  # tell everyone above my parent that i'm down here in this mess
  for ((j = i - 2; j >= 0; j--)); do
    ip -n "${ns[j]}" route add "${ip[i]}" via "${ip[j+1]}"
  done
done
```

Comment: Nice work! I've changed yours to be the accepted answer. @neutronscott

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get this working with Linux Namespaces, which are currently the Linux equivalent of `vrf`. This is just a handwritten POC, you'd probably want to wrap this in a script and generate procedurally.

Took me well over 8 hours to figure out, hopefully it will help others in future.

#### Final result

```
$ ping 172.16.101.2
PING 172.16.101.2 (172.16.101.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.16.101.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=0.064 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.101.2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=0.043 ms

$ traceroute 172.16.101.2
traceroute to 172.16.101.2 (172.16.101.2), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  172.16.100.2 (172.16.100.2)  0.055 ms  0.006 ms  0.004 ms
 2  172.16.101.2 (172.16.101.2)  0.059 ms  0.009 ms  0.009 ms
```

#### Solution

```
# add the namespaces
ip netns add hop1
ip netns add hop2

ip netns exec hop1   ip link set lo up
ip netns exec hop2   ip link set lo up

ip netns exec hop1   sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
ip netns exec hop2   sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

# create host link to first hop
ip link add hop1 type veth peer name veth1

ip addr change 172.16.100.1/24 dev hop1
ip link set hop1 up

ip link set veth1 netns hop1
ip netns exec hop1   ip link set veth1 name eth0
ip netns exec hop1   ip link set eth0 up
ip netns exec hop1   ip addr change 172.16.100.2/24 dev eth0

# create hop2 (link to hop1)
ip link add veth0 type veth peer name veth1

ip link set veth0 netns hop1
ip netns exec hop1   ip link set veth0 name eth1
ip netns exec hop1   ip link set eth1 up
ip netns exec hop1   ip addr change 172.16.101.1/24 dev eth1

ip link set veth1 netns hop2
ip netns exec hop2   ip link set veth1 name eth0
ip netns exec hop2   ip link set eth0 up
ip netns exec hop2   ip addr change 172.16.101.2/24 dev eth0

# set namespace routing
ip netns exec hop1   route add default gw 172.16.101.2
ip netns exec hop2   route add default gw 172.16.101.1

# set host routing
route add -net 172.16.101.0/24 gw 172.16.100.2
```